# Some objects remain white when rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm a rookie in blender and did the shape of a house. I imported some objects in the interior and they all come with nice colors. Even the exterior. Not the imported car port and the olive trees.

What am I missing to show the colors on all the objects?

I tried fbx and obj. Both remain white. Whereas other objects come with colour immediately. I must be a little thing I don't understand.

Any clue?

[image]

Thanks heaps.

Here is the shader tree of the olive tree.

[image]

And this is what the olive tree looks rendered. https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/exterior/landscape/set-of-6-olive-trees

Comment: Can you show a screenshot where you see them with "nice colors" and the shader nodetree on one of those materials?

Comment: @Carlo added. Thanks for looking at it. The outdoor lounge for example has nice colours. The interior table, lamp, glasses, etc. all these imports worked fine (all with fbx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: base color circled]

[image: base color] This is where the color of the material is set. If the trees came with an image texture, add it as an Image Texture node and connect it here. If not, set this color to something besides white.

Comment: thanks to both of you. works like a charm.